# When Delete button hit, image needs to be deleted from table, error message showing instead

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I have a gallery where I want the user to be able to update the image title and delete the image if they wish. My update the title code works as expected, and I assumed the delete code wouldn't be far off the same.

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tblImage`";

    $result = $conn -> query($query);

    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
    {
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <a href="<?php echo $row['fldFilePath']; ?>" data-lightbox="gallery" data-title="<?php echo $row['fldName']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['fldFilePath']; ?>" class="ImgRound"></a>
    <label>Image Name: <?php echo $row['fldName']; ?></label>
    <input name ="img-title" type ="text" placeholder="Enter New Image Title...">
    <button type="submit" value ="<?php echo $row['fldName'] ?>" name="update_title" class="ImgRound size-btn">Update</button>
    <button type="submit" value ="<?php echo $row['fldName'] ?>" name="delete" class="ImgRound size-btn">Delete</button>
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['update_title']))
        {
                $imgTitle = $_POST['img-title'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `tblImage` SET `fldName` = ? WHERE `fldName` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $imgTitle, $_POST['update_title']) or die($stmt->error);
        if ($stmt->execute())
            {
                header("Refresh:0");
            }   
        else {

                die($stmt->error);
             }

         }
    }
?>
```

As soon as I add in the below code in before the last closing `}` :

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
    {
        $imgTitle = $_POST['img-title'];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `tblImage` WHERE `tblImage`.`fldName` = ?"); 
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $imgTitle, $_POST['delete']) or die($stmt->error);
        if ($stmt->execute())
            {
                header("Refresh:0");
            }   
        else {
                die($stmt->error);
            }
    }
```

Error appearing is: ***Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement***

Any guidance to what I have done incorrectly? Perhaps the query, or should I perhaps place the value in the delete button of the File Path as appose to the Image Name - `fldName`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your second prepared statement only has one bind parameter(`\`fldName\` = ?`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `tblImage` WHERE `tblImage`.`fldImageID` = ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $imgTitle, $_POST['delete']) or die($stmt->error);
```

You have one question mark (parameter), thus two variables is too many.

This should become

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `tblImage` WHERE `tblImage`.`fldImageID` = ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['delete']) or die($stmt->error);
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, thank you Ben and K.Haydock so much that was absolutely correct, now running fine. I'm so sorry to waste both your time.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you only have one parameter `?` however you have `"ss"`, delete one of those and rerun the query.